# I'm trying to change constraints when the 1st of the month falls on a Friday/Saturday with 30-31 days

Tags: objective-c

How to get this to work for the whole month. I am able to call the method for that day.
So, what I'm trying to do is - If this month has 31 days and the 1st of the month is on a Friday or Saturday then use certain constraints. I have been trying for several days now on how to get this to work for the whole month. I have looked at almost all the posts on NSDate and tried to find a similar question, to see if it has been asked before. I'm finding it difficult to wrap my head around this. What am I not doing? Thank you for your time in advance.

```
  NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
  NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]  initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
  NSRange currentRange = [gregorian rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth forDate:now];
  NSInteger wantedWeekDay = 6; //for day of week
  NSInteger numberOfDays = currentRange.length;
  NSDateComponents *component = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:now];
  NSInteger firstDateWeekDay = component.weekday;
  NSLog(@"First Date Week Day = %ld",(long)firstDateWeekDay);
  NSLog(@"weekday : %li",(long)firstDateWeekDay);

  if (wantedWeekDay == firstDateWeekDay) {

    if (numberOfDays ==31) {
              NSLog(@"Yes");
         }


     }else {
          NSLog(@"no");
     }
```

Comment: `now` is today, did you try to create a day for the first day of the month?

Comment: I know what you mean, I'm not quite sure how to go about that but I'll experiment and work it, thank you.

Comment: @Wileke I did what you said and it works like a charm. Thank you very much.